# Why doesn't my <package>.lintian-overrides work?

Tags: package-management, lintian

I'm packaging `cgreen` for Ubuntu working currently on 15.10 and in my debian directory I've created `cgreen.lintian-overrides` as per [the lintian manual](https://lintian.debian.org/manual/section-2.4.html) and [the New Maintainers Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#lintiand). It has this content:

```
cgreen binary : non-dev-pkg-with-shlib-symlink *
cgreen binary : package-name-doesnt-match-sonames *
```

(I've tried many variations of this...)

When I run `debuild`, or just `lintian` I still get those warnings. `lintian -d` does not indicate that it has found any overrides, but the debug message says "if there where any", so to me it is unclear if it found and read my file or if there is some format error.

There was some indication that profiles could set some tags to non-overrideable, but I've inspected the profiles in /usr/share/lintian/profiles/ubuntu and the tags in my override does not seem to be disabled there.

Why does not `lintian` respect my overrides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this was overrides for a binary package they need to be installed using `dh_lintian` before `lintian` is run. And actually before the package is being made by `dh_builddeb`. And even more the override files (`usr/share/lintian/overrides/<package>`) installed must be included in the md5sums. So the sequence in the `rules`file need to be explicitly this:

```
...
dh_lintian
dh_md5sums
dh_builddeb
```

I don't know if `dh` implicitly does it this way but I couldn't use it, therefore the explicit list of `dh_*`.

Comment: PLEASE give complete example.